# While solving this 'data comparison' related question on applying 'count function' on this problem, I am getting output as zero

Tags: sql, postgresql

Condition 1: Count the number of requests created on March 13, 2017.

Condition 2:  Specify the upper bound by adding 1 to the lower bound.

**-- Count requests created on March 13, 2017

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM evanston311
WHERE date_created >= '2017-03-13' AND 
      date_created < '2017-03-12'::date + 1;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Your second part is not correct.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM evanston311
WHERE date_created >= '2017-03-13'::date AND
      date_created < '2017-03-13'::date + interval '1 day';
```

The date in the second part should be the same as the date in the first part.

Comment: Hi Gordon,Appreciate your prompt reply. But, this one is also resulting in the same error. As far as source is concerned, it is evanston311 data and the course is date comparison from Datacamp

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count(*)
  FROM evanston311
 WHERE date_created >= '2017-03-13'
   AND date_created < '2017-03-13'::date + 1;

Both the answers had a common line of thought and by integrating them, this answer gives the required output i.e count = 33

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count for a specific date just use DATE_TRUNC and look for equality. No range setting needed.

```
select count(*)
  from evanston311
 where date_trunc('day' date_created) = '2017-03-13'::date;
```